# How to turn an existing one-drive filesystem into a RAIDZ?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I have a single large (8Tb) drive, and would like to buy two more and make a 3-drive RAIDZ1.

My problem is, there is no easy way to back up the current contents -- it is too big. The entire drive is a single traditional filesystem (UFS version 1 in FreeBSD parlance).

I think, it is possible to:

1. Create a "degraded" RAIDZ1 with the two new drives.
2. Copy the files to this degraded array.
3. Add the older disk to the array -- and initiate its recovery/rebuild.

Could someone help me with the actual commands for each of the steps? My system is FreeBSD, but it probably does not matter -- ZFS is ZFS...

Comment: The crucial thing in that answer is that the file you create to be a fake disk should be a **sparse** file, so that it appears to be the same size (8TB) as your pool disks without actually taking up that much space.   In short: Create the pool with the two new drives and the fake drive, offline the fake drive, rsync your data to it from your current 8TB drive, and then add it to the pool.

Comment: Note that since you do not have a backup, if anything goes wrong you risk losing **ALL** of your data.  The point of no return is when you add the original drive to the pool, you can revert at any time before that.   You should try to back up as much of your data and config files as possible, prioritising your most important or irreplaceable data (and de-prioritise stuff that you downloaded from the internet, it can all be re-fetched if necessary).

Comment: It would be more expensive but much safer to just buy a third new 8TB drive to create the pool with.  If your data is worth more to you than the price of the extra drive and you can afford it, then just do that.

Comment: At about $200 apiece, I can barely afford two new drives. You want me to spend $200 more? This is a home computer :)

Comment: I don't *want* you to do anything.  I'm making sure that you're aware of the risk and suggesting a way to avoid that risk.  What you do with that information is entirely up to you.